# How to evaluate $_2F_1(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2}; \sin^{2}(x))=\cos(x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series, hypergeometric-function

$$_2F_1(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2}; \sin^{2}(x))=\cos(x)$$

I plug these values into the definition of the hypergeometric function:

$$_2F_1(a,b,c,x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{a^{\overline{n}}b^{\overline{n}}}{c^{\overline{n}}}\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$$

And I obtain:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{\frac{1}{2}^{\overline{n}}\left(-\frac{1^{\overline{n}}}{2}\right)}{\frac{1^{\overline{n}}}{2}}\frac{(\sin^{2}(x))^n}{n!}$$

I don't know how to simplify the $-\dfrac{1^{\overline{n}}}{2}$ and $n!$.

$$-\dfrac{1^{\overline{n}}}{2}=\left(-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\left(\dfrac{3}{2}\right)...\left(\dfrac{2n-3}{n}\right)$$

$$n!=(n-3)(n-2)(n-1)n...$$

Also, what should I do with the $n$ power of $\sin^2(x)$

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: What is $k$? ${}{}$

Comment: @Shaun I forgot to add the mathematical expression. Sorry, immediately edited.

Comment: @metamorphy Nicely stated! I see what you mean now. I think you should post a short and succinct answer so I can upvote for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually $_2F_1(a,b;a;z)=(1-z)^{-b}$ for $|z|<1$ and any $a,b$ (well, with $a\notin\mathbb{Z}_{\leqslant 0}$). Indeed, both are equal to $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b(b+1)\dots(b+n-1)z^n/n!$, by definition of $_2F_1$ for the LHS, and by the [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) for the RHS.

Answer (score 5):

First of all we can cancel one parameter:
$$\mbox{$_2$}F_1(a,b;a; x)=\mbox{$_1$}F_0(b;;x)$$

Further:
$$
\mbox{$_1$}F_0\left(-\frac12;;x\right)=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{\left(-\frac12\right)^\overline{n}}{n!}x^n=\sum_{n\ge0}\binom{\frac12}n(-x)^n=\sqrt{1-x}.
$$

Comment: I have a question. $_2F_1$ means the Gaussian hypergeometric function. What is $_1F_0$? What do these subscripts around $F$ mean?

Comment: @JamesWarthington It is the [generalized hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function).